# Oracle recursive query to find chain of given length

Tags: sql, oracle11g, recursive-query

I have a table TABLE that has two fields OLD_ID, NEW_ID that represents ids of merged data.

We can have

(OLD_ID='1',NEW_ID='20')

or

(OLD_ID='4',NEW_ID='50')

(OLD_ID='50',NEW_ID='70')

etc. There are no infinite loops but there might have been many merges of an original id so the chain can be 2,3,4, more long.

How do I write a query that returns all the chains of a given length?

I started going down something like

```
select * from TABLE t1 as m1 where NEW_ID in
(select OLD_ID from t1 as m2 where OLD_ID in
(select NEW_ID from t1 as m3 where m1.NEW_ID <> NEW_ID))
```

but this doesnt work and is not scalable.

Comment: Same data and expected results would help as I'm unsure if you consider 1,2 2,3 a chain length of 2.  and then would 2,3 3,4 also be a chain length of 2? even though 1,4 is also a chain length of 3. but contains 2 2 length chains as well.  Do you want to see it or only those where the entire length is considered?

Comment: If there is a 1,2,2,3 there is no 2,3,3,4 (or the other way around). Basically the ids in one chain will not be in any other chain.

Comment: yes but if the entire chain is 3 levels and you ask for all chains that are 2 levels then 1,2:2:3 is a lvl 2 chain.  as is 2,3:3,4 while the entire chain would be 1-4.  It doesn't sound like you want sub chains to count you look at the whole chain size to determine level; and my last update should give you what you're  after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle can use [`connect by`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) to do this:  Connect by offers several pseudo columns which may help out as well.

```
with CTE (Old_ID, New_ID) as (
Select 0,1 from dual union all
Select 1,2 from dual union all
Select 2,3 from dual union all
Select 3,4 from dual union all
Select 4,5 from dual union all
Select 5,6 from dual union all 
Select 7,8 from dual union all
Select 8,9 from dual union all
Select 9,10 from dual union all
Select 10,11 from dual union all 
Select 12,13 from dual)

SELECT Old_ID OID
     , New_ID NID
     , level lvl
     , SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(OLD_ID, '/') "Path"  --not needed but nice pseudo col 
     , CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF "IsLeaf" --needed to exclude subchains.
FROM cte A  --Update this line w/ your table name
WHERE   --LEVEL = 1 and 
   CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF =1  --this is how we only look at chains that have no other siblings
Start with OLD_ID not in (Select new_ID from CTE)  --This ensures we look only at values that are themselves not new_IDs In other words, the oldest ancestor). -- and update the cte table name in the subquery here to your table name
connect by NOCYCLE prior new_ID=OLD_ID   --added nocycle.
```

As this allows you to only traverse the entire structure once. look at the length of an entire chain and not subdivide it.  isleaf ensures we only look at the records having a full chain in determining the chain length.

This gives us:

```
+----+----+---+--------------+----+
|OID |NID |LVL| Path         |leaf|
+----+----+---+--------------+----+
|  5 |  6 | 6 | /0/1/2/3/4/5 | 1  |
| 10 | 11 | 4 | /7/8/9/10    | 1  |
| 12 | 13 | 1 | /12          | 1  |
+----+----+---+--------------+----+
```

You can uncomment out `level = 1` and substitute the level desired.

you may need to subtract 1 depending how you count levels. Some people like to start at 0; this starts at 1.

- a 5/6 is lvl 1   (some may say this is 0)
- a 6/7 is lvl 2   (some may say this is 1 and so on)

Comment: What is dual? where is the table name specified?

Comment: common table expression aliased CTE is just sample data.  Dual is a ORACLE table which contains 1 record.  Oracle requires a table in a from clause unlike SQL server or mySQL which can just select 1.  Dual provides as a way of creating data on the fly.   What you need to do is replace cte with your table name and ignore dual sample data in CTE which references dual.  basically replace the 2 CTE's in the query following the cte.  I've put a blank line for clarity.  More on [Dual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries009.htm)

Comment: Still More on Dual [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1562813956388)

Comment: I get stuck in an infinite loop it seems. Have the query running for 15 minutes.

Comment: How many records do you have the where clause so that it only traces the ... I think I need to add the `nocycle`  element so it will not loop if you have a loop in your data.  added nocycle to last line of select. so if loops exist in the data the system recognizes it and escapes.  you can use [`CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns001.htm#i1009434) to identify the offending records:

Comment: @user2175783 still running? :P

Comment: No got it to run. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE for this:

```
With Cte As 
(
    Select  Old_Id, New_Id, 1 As Level
    From    YourTable
    Where   Old_Id = 4
    Union All
    Select  T2.Old_Id, T2.New_Id, T1.Level + 1
    From    Cte         T1
    Join    YourTable   T2  On  T1.New_Id = T2.Old_Id
)
Select   *
From     Cte
Order By Level
```

Comment: This includes subchains, needs to have the column alias defined since recursions is occurring and uses a RESERVED `level`   So I think it would be: `Cte(Old_ID, new_ID, Lvl) As 
(
    Select  Old_Id, New_Id, 1 As lvl
    From    YourTable
    Union All
    Select  T2.Old_Id, T2.New_Id, T1.lvl + 1
    From    Cte         T1
    Join    YourTable   T2  On  T1.New_Id = T2.Old_Id
)
Select   *
From     Cte
where lvl = 4
Order By lvl`  not sure why you use old_ID = 4 as base for recursive query as we don't know what is the "start" in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than write it recursively, if the number of links is limited, perhaps simply join one more than you think you need:

```
 select T1.OLD_ID as ID1
      , T1.NEW_ID as ID2
      , T2.NEW_ID as ID3
      , T3.NEW_ID as ID4
      , T4.NEW_ID as ID5
      , T5.NEW_ID as ID6
      , T6.NEW_ID as ID7
 from table T1
 left join table T2
    on T1.NEW_ID = T2.OLD_ID
 left join table T3
    on T2.NEW_ID = T3.OLD_ID
 left join table T4
    on T3.NEW_ID = T4.OLD_ID
 left join table T5
    on T4.NEW_ID = T5.OLD_ID
 left join table T6
    on T5.NEW_ID = T6.OLD_ID
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. It gives me repeated data like ID1 ID2 ID3 03491628 00434555 03491628
03491628 00434555 03491628
03491628 00434555 03491628
03491628 00434555 03491628

Comment: `WHERE T1.OLD_ID not in (Select new_ID from yourtable)` add this to the select and you'll get what I think you're after @user2175783 and a case statement to give you a level in select `case when T1.New_ID is not null then 1 else 0 end +
      case when T2.New_ID is not null then 1 else 0 end +
      case when T3.New_ID is not null then 1 else 0 end +
      case when T4.New_ID is not null then 1 else 0 end +
      case when T5.New_ID is not null then 1 else 0 end +
      case when T6.New_ID is not null then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: I do not think I can improve it without understanding the input table.  I assumed that both columns were NOT NULL.  What would be the meaning if either column held a NULL value. +1 on @xQbert request for sample data.